# Mock Insert returning 0 as entity.Id but working when app is hosted and request using Curl

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

```
    public class ArticlesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IArticleRepository _articleRepository;

        public ArticlesController(IArticleRepository articleRepository)
        {
            _articleRepository = articleRepository;
        }

 public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]ArticleModel model)
        {
            var article = create article object by fill input from model ;
            await _articleRepository.InsertAsync(article);
            return Created($"articles/{article.Id}", article);
        }
    }
```

---

```
public interface IArticleRepository : IGenericRepository<Article>
    {
    }
```

---

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : BaseEntity, new()
    {
 public async Task InsertAsync(T entity)
        {
            _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

--
When i mock the insert , it return 0 as entity.Id , but when i run after hosting the app . The Insert works and return entity.id > 0. What am i doing wrong ? I am pretty new to moq and unit testing
-- Test Method

```
     private Mock<IArticleRepository> _articleRepositoryMock = new Mock<IArticleRepository>();

        public ArticlesControllerTests()
        {
            _articlesController = new ArticlesController(_articleRepositoryMock.Object);
        }

 [Fact]
        public async Task Post_SingleItem()
        {
            var article = Builder<Article>.CreateNew().Build();
            _articleRepositoryMock.As<IGenericRepository<Article>>().Setup(m=>m.InsertAsync(article)).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

            var result = await _articlesController.Post(atricleModel);

            //verify after casting the result to desired object and check .Id > 0 fails


        }
```

Comment: Where are you defining your mock object's ID? Did you debug your test and look at the ID that your mock object has?

Comment: The Mock object at the (var article = Builder<Article>.CreateNew().Build();) does have Id , but once it is passed to the controller . only the needed param other than ID (Database primary key in EF) is filled and sent to InsertAsync . Won't the Id will be generated by EF on successful save?

Comment: If you're mocking the repository, then it's not interacting with EF. That's the point of mocking.

Comment: Sorry , so the mock object won't return an ID on successful processing of InsertAsync ? I can use only Assert.Verify if that method is called once with successful Task.Completed ?

Comment: The mock will do whatever you tell it to do. In this case, you're telling the mock to return `Task.CompletedTask`. That's all it does.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @DanielMann . had hard time to understand why the Id was 0 on mock test and when the application is hosted , it is not.